# postgis - ST_Intersects not working, different measurement system

Tags: postgis

I have 2 tables, parcels and units. Parcels is in Meters, and Units is in Feet

I'm attempting the following:

```
SELECT p.pin, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(p.geom,4326)) as geojson
  FROM susquehanna_parcels p, units_pa u
  WHERE ST_Intersects(p.geom, u.the_geom)
    AND u.unit_name='Traver E North 07-081'
```

I'm not getting any results because the measurement system is off.  You can see I"m trying to get a decimal degrees out (which works in other queries), but since there aren't any intersections with the data, there are no results.

How can I convert either p.geom to feet on the fly or u.the_geom to meters on the fly so the ST_Intersects can work properly?

Answer (score 0):

If `parcels` is in meter and `units` in feet, as long as the measure unit depends on the SRID, they aren't in the same SRID. You should make sure both geoms are in the same SRID if you are checking if they intersect.

```sql
SELECT p.pin, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(p.geom,4326)) as geojson
  FROM susquehanna_parcels p, units_pa u
  WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(p.geom, 4326), ST_Transform(u.the_geom, 4326))
    AND u.unit_name='Traver E North 07-081'
```

I used EPSG 4326 here because is the same you used before but any other should be fine as long as is the same for both geoms inside `ST_Intersects`

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. However, I did notice during the import of the data into postgis using shp2pgsql that it used SRID 2271, so not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Maybe one of your geoms does not have any SRID defined because it was not set properly in the shp2pgsql. You can set the SRID with ST_setSRID or check if the SRID is correct with ST_SRID